# Barcode of format CODE_128 is scanning incorrectly via @zxing/ngx-scanner

Tags: angular, angular7, zxing, barcode-scanner

I am using [@zxing/ngx-scanner](https://github.com/zxing-js/ngx-scanner/wiki/Getting-Started) to scan barcodes. I can scan barcodes of format QR_CODE and DATA_MATRIX using my laptop camera. I now want to scan barcode of format CODE_128. But the library takes time to scan and when it scans..it scans incorrectly.

Has anyone faced similar issues? How do I rectify this issue?

I am using Angular 7 and ngx-scanner version 2.0.1.
I am trying in Chrome browser on Windows 10.

Code:

```
In HTML:
<zxing-scanner #scanner start="true" (scanSuccess)="myFn($event)" [formats]="['QR_CODE', 'EAN_13', 'CODE_128', 'DATA_MATRIX']"></zxing-scanner>
```

```
In ts:
import { ZXingScannerComponent } from '@zxing/ngx-scanner';

export class myClass implements OnInit {
 @ViewChild('scanner') scanner: ZXingScannerComponent;
 hasDevices: boolean = false;
 hasPermission: boolean;
 availableDevices: MediaDeviceInfo[] = [];
 currentDevice: MediaDeviceInfo;

 constructor(private zone: NgZone) {
  window['angularComponentReference'] = {
    zone: this.zone,
    componentFn: (searchcontent: any) =>
      window['scannerOutput'](searchcontent),
      component: this,
  };
 }

 ngOnInit() {
  this.scanner.camerasFound.subscribe((devices: MediaDeviceInfo[]) => {
     this.hasDevices = true;
     this.availableDevices = devices;
  });
  this.scanner.camerasNotFound.subscribe(() => {
     this.hasDevices = false;
  });
  this.scanner.scanComplete.subscribe((result: Result) => {
     this.qrResult = result;
     this.hasPermission = false;
  });
  this.scanner.permissionResponse.subscribe((perm: boolean) => {
    this.hasPermission = perm;
  });
 }

 myFn(resultString) {
   console.log(resultString);
 }

}
```

Update:
Sample of Barcode I need to scan
[image]

Comment: Are you certain that its a CODE_128 barcode? There are several types of 1D barcodes.

Comment: @ChrisBD not 100% certain.. but the sample received seems to be CODE_128... attaching a sample barcode that I need to scan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved. For 1-D barcodes, we need to hold the barcode horizontally for it to scan correctly.

For more info, I had created github issue for the same: https://github.com/zxing-js/ngx-scanner/issues/296